# How to create a pagination in Laravel and Vue js?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I´ve been trying to do some basic Laravel and VueJS stuff. The problem here is that I can't figure out why the pagination isn´t displaying. As a note, my VueJS skills are terrible.
Here is some code for some references.:
Controller:

```
    public function index()
{
    $news = News::latest()
        ->with('user')
        ->with('media')
        ->paginate(2);
       
    $news = $news->each(function ($news, int $key) {
        $news->image = $news->media->first()?->getUrl();
        $news->unsetRelation('media');
    });
    
    return inertia('News/Index', [
        'news' => $news,
    ]);
}
```

Index.vue:

```
import Pagination from '@/Components/Pagination.vue';
  <template>  
<Pagination :links="news.links"/>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        news: {
            type: Array,
            required: true,
        },
    }
}    
</script>
```

imported pagination file:

```
    <template>
    <div>
        <Component 
          :is="link.url ? 'Link' : 'span'"
          v-for="link in links"
          :href="link.label"
          :class="link.url ? '' : text-gray-500"
        />
    </div>
  </template>
    
  <script>
  export default {
    props: {
      links: Array,
    },
  }
</script>
```

Comment: first of all see how paginate data is dd it first you can understand that. Paginate data are item page number and query if any. See laracast with inertiajs there will be that topic.

Comment: $news = $news->each(function ($news, int $key) {
        $news->image = $news->media->first()?->getUrl();
        $news->unsetRelation('media');
    }); this is not needed to do

Comment: @PuneetSharma 
As you said, I´ve added the dd to see what I get. And frankly, it´s not helping me out. I get two Arrays that contain one of the entries from the DB. It only provides the two paginated files. The others have vanished.

Comment: please post that data also.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer. So I figuered out what the issue was. It kicked out the data from the pagination in the each function.

Comment: First of all, please show the result of  "news" , and in pagination component send whole "news" rather "news.links"